# Translated node overwrites other languages

Tags: 7, nodes, i18n-l10n

I have a content type with a multivalue text field. Each time I add a translation, the translated node overwrites the source node. Also happens in opposite direction. It seems that whatever I do, the field always overwrites. The node title doesn't though.

I have synchronisation turned off on my content type. What could it be?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do editing of node using path prefix of language in which the node you edit is. So, this would look like:

[site-domain]/[language-path-prefix]/[path-to-node-edit]

You need to enable 'URL' detection method in '/admin/config/regional/language/configure'

Let me know if this is working for you.

Comment: Yep that's what I'm doing, and it's still overwriting it.